# unable to access web site

Tags: http, web

My website ([harlequinf40.info](http://harlequinf40.info)) (WordPress) is only intermittently accessible.
On my home WiFi network, it is accessible from Chrome on my W7 PC but not in Chrome on my W8 laptop or my Android phone. They both return a blank screen.

On the phone, using a proxy server, I get "the requested URL was not recognised as a valid URL", whereas on my W7 PC, using the same proxy server ([free-proxyserver.com](http://free-proxyserver.com)), I get to the site OK.
Some of my users are also unable to access the site, others are getting on fine!

I'm not getting a 404 error, or any response...just a blank screen.

I have started to talk to my ISP, but it's a big telco and they're not very responsive(!)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inspected your HTML code on Android phone and found that your head tag contains the culprit. 
I did it by checking:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" id="main-css" href="http://harlequinF40.info/wp-content/plugins/gallery-bank/assets/css/main.css?ver=3.6.1" type="text/css" media="all">
...
</head>
```

Found this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
       z-index: 997;
       background: #fafafa;
       width: 100%;
       top: 0;
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Remove the "**display: none;**" and the site will not show blank page.

I am not sure whats your W8 laptop screen resolution, I think there is no problem on your site server. But the problem is on your code. I suggest you to contact your developer. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: What about the content of the head element caused the "the requested URL was not recognised as a valid URL" error?

Comment: That looks like a valid URL, and it resolves in my browser. Why does it cause the previously mentioned error message?

Comment: I just checked on my Android phone and the site is blank. There is miscoded CSS media queries.

Comment: Hi @Dainwayat, I don't see how that explains the site working intermittantly. The W8 laptop is a 10" screen at 1366x768. Please expand.

Comment: But I removed the display:none from the css as suggested and problem solved! excellent, thanks